# print stylesheets - how to print all pages of paginated content?

Tags: css, printing, pagination

I'd like to use CSS to specify a stylesheet for printing (instead of the "print friendly view"). The problem is that my web site has long article content that is paginated. When printing a paginated article using CSS, only the current single page gets printed instead of the whole article.

Is there any way to control the printing so that when the user prints the "all pages" view is printed instead of just a single page?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to create custom output, just for printing. Same stylesheet, just with all the content on one go instead of paginated.

I sometimes put a parameter "printmode=1" or something, then load the content into a hidden iframe on the same page and print it from in there.